# Prove that there is a number that is not square-free

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, polynomials

How do I prove that for any polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x], \operatorname{deg} f \geq 1$, there are infinitely many $n$, such that $f(n)$ is not squarefree?

I have two solutions, one of them is good, correct and quite "straightforward", but the second is very controversial, and I want you to explain to me why it does not work.

$1)$ For large $n, f(n)$ becomes a large integer so is divisible by some prime $p$ say. This means that the polynomial $f(X)$ modulo $p$ factors as $f(X) \equiv(X-n) g(X) \bmod p$. There are two cases to consider.

- $f(n) \equiv 0 \bmod p^{2}$
- $f(n) \not \equiv 0 \bmod p^{2}$ which means that $g(n) \not \equiv 0 \bmod p$.

In the first case $f(n)$ is not square free. In the second case, the derivative $f^{\prime}(x)$ satisfies $f^{\prime}(n) \not \equiv 0 \bmod p$, so we can use [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) to find an $n^{\prime} \equiv n \bmod p$ for which
$f\left(n^{\prime}\right) \equiv 0 \bmod p^{2}$. This means that $f\left(n^{\prime}\right)$ is not square free.

I liked this solution, I also have a question: is it necessary to add a restriction on the number $p$ here, it must be taken large enough so that the derivative of the polynomial modulo $p$ does not become identically zero, then everything works?

$2)$ Consider the polynomial $f(x)=c_{k} x^{k}+c_{k-1} x^{k-1}+\ldots+c_{1} x^{1}+c_{0}$, where $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x], \operatorname{deg} f \geq 1$. For any non-squarefree $f(n)$ there are exactly $\operatorname{deg} f$ such $n$ that $f(n)=c_{k} n^{k}+c_{k-1} n^{k-1}+\ldots+c_{1} n^{1}+c_{0}$ - this equality is true (by the fundamental theorem of algebra). This means that since there are infinitely many non-square-free $f(n)$, there also exist infinitely many $n$, that the number $f(n)$ is not square-free.

Comment: Your second solution makes very little sense to me. Can you elaborate on the "This means that that since there are ..." part? Are you assuming that there are infinitely many such $f(n)$? Are you forgetting that $n$ needs to be an integer (which is an assumption in the first solution, but not stated in the question specifically)?

Comment: @Calvin Lin This is the problem, that this solution is not mine and I myself do not understand it, I will try to rephrase it, but it will hardly help.

Comment: In which case, it is nonsensical to me and doesn't seem valid. If it's from a textbook, then I might reconsider. If it's someone's online musings, then I will just move on. $\quad$ I have various issues with it (like why are there exactly $\deg f$ such n, which doesn't account for complex roots, non-integer roots, multiple roots, etc).

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thank you, but what about my question under the first solution?

Comment: Yes, something’s missing from the first solution since $4x^2+2$ isn’t divisible by $4$ for any $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ gives only square-free values from some point on, then it should be square-free always. This is because if $d^2\mid f(k)$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ then $d^2\mid f(k+md^2)$. But this cannot happen and [here is why.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45043/integer-polynomial-of-degree-1-all-of-whose-values-are-square-free)